# How do I get GoLang's http.HandleFunc() to work without error?

Tags: json, function, go, handler, httplistener

I am trying to create a GoLang http.HandleFunc() that will listen for post requests and parse a json file.  The Handler seems to fail as it starts and returns an error:

> 2017/01/24 13:35:08 listen tcp :8080: bind: Only one usage of each
>   socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

I am assuming that it is throwing a fatal error.

Below is my function:

```
 http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {

        //debug
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(request.URL.Path))

        var m Message

        if request.Body == nil {
            http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)                
            return
        }

        err := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&m)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
            return
        }
 })
 log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
```

How can I get this Handler to work and not get the error?

Comment: Your code snippet doesn't make any sense; why is there a `defer res.Body.Close()` call "in the middle on nowhere"?

Comment: This error indicates that there is another process or thread listening on the port already. Do you perhaps have another program on your computer serving to port `8080`?

Comment: @TimCooper I'm not sure where it is supposed to go?  Any suggestions?

Comment: @JordanLewis I ran  netstat -nc TCP | find "8080"   and got nothing back

Comment: I figured it out.  The Handler continues to run as a process on Windows until you either shut down Eclipse, or kill the process.  After you do this, you can run the handler without error.  How can I get the handler to stop in the code for testing purposes?

Answer (score 1):

I've remedied several of the problems with your code and made best guesses around missing information. Here is sample working code that will accept a message that has "name" and "text" fields:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
  "html"
  "log"
  "net/http"
)

type Message struct {
  Name string `json:"name"`
  Text string `json:"text"`
}

func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", func(w http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hello, %q", html.EscapeString(request.URL.Path))

    var m Message

    if request.Body == nil {
      http.Error(w, "Please send a request body", 400)
      return
    }

    err := json.NewDecoder(request.Body).Decode(&m)
    if err != nil {
      http.Error(w, err.Error(), 400)
      return
    }

    log.Println(m)
  })

  log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Comment: I cannot find much difference.  I see that you added the main function and the struct, which I have.  I was only showing the Handler fucntion and log, not the whole of my code.

Comment: Understood. I completed the code so that I can run it and verify that it works - that information might make for a better question.

Comment: OK, thanks.  Please let me know if you are getting the error.

Comment: I am not getting the error, as indicated in comments above you must have a process hanging onto that port.